# diffrence in object decleration in class

Tags: java

In below code what is difference between obj1 & obj2 ?
My question is in syntax -

```
Classname1 objectname = new Classname2();
```

May be Classname1=Classname2

what is significance of `Classname1`.

```
// Superclass
class Base {
    public static void display() {
        System.out.println("Static or class method from Base");
    }

}

// Subclass
class Derived extends Base {


       public void print() {
         System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Derived");
   }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[ ])  {
       Base obj1 = new Derived();
       Derived obj2 = new Derived();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Classname1 `?

Comment: It can be any class  in java which i have declare some where. Mainly i want to ask what is difference between obj1 & obj2 in my code if any?

Comment: Possible [duplcate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807029/superclass-reference-to-subclass-object-showing-same-behaviour-as-subclass-refer)

Comment: Possibly duplicates [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
Classname1 objectname = new Classname2();
```

`Classname1` is the type of the variable `objectname`; `Classname2` is the type of the object we're assigning to that variable. From that line we can infer that either `Classname1` is an interface that `Classname2` implements (like `HashMap` implements `Map`), or that `Classname2` is a subclass (directly or indirectly) of `Classname1`, like `HashMap` extends `AbstractMap`.

In a comment you said:

> what is difference between obj1 & obj2 in my code if any?

I assume you're talking about this code:

```
Base obj1 = new Derived();
Derived obj2 = new Derived();
```

There's no difference in the *objects* that are assigned to those variables, but there's a difference in the *type* of the variables and therefore the type of reference you have to the object: The object that `obj1` points to has a `print` method, but you can't access it via `obj1` because the type of the reference you have is `Base`, not `Derived`, and `Base` doesn't have `print`. In contrast, you can access `print` via `obj2` because the type of the reference is `Derived`.

Comment: you are saying i cant access print method of derived class via obj1. what happen if i have same print method in base class also.in that case which print method will execute.suppose i have situation like this http://pastebin.com/tJcpuj52     In this code output will be "hello from derived".  Means via obj1 i have access print method of derived class not base class.it will be grate if you help me out of this confusion.

Comment: @nikhiljain: Right, if you define `print` on the base class, then references of that type can access it. The one they access, in Java, is the `print` from the *object's* type (not the reference's type). That's called [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) (specifically, subtype polymorphism).

Comment: So in my code object's type of obj1 & obj2 is derived right? can you tell me one think what is difference between  object type & reference type.

Comment: @nikhiljain: The type of the *object* is the type you used with `new`. The type of the *reference* is the type you used when declaring your variable (or method argument, etc.).

Comment: @nikhiljain: For completeness about polymorphism: There are some languages (such as C++ and C#) where which `print` gets used may be the reference's type's `print` **or** the object's type's `print`, depending on how `print` is defined. A "non-virtual" method will use the reference's type; a "virtual" method will use the object's type. Java only has virtual methods. (C#, sadly, defaults to non-virtual methods and you have to explicitly declare them virtual.)

Comment: suppose i have added static in both print method(base or derived class) at that time why  obj1 access print from the reference type(not from object's type)whether static word make the method non-virtual

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81638/discussion-between-nikhil-jain-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @nikhiljain: Search for "override static java" here on SO and you'll find explanations for that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the difference in these lines:

```
Base obj1 = new Derived();
Derived obj2 = new Derived();
```

In both the cases the object constructed is of class `Derived`but references are different. You are able to use reference of type `Base` because `Derived` is also `Base` (assuming `Derived` extends `Base`) hence can be used. But which one should we prefer? The former one because it makes robust design.

Consider the Collections Framework in Java which has a `List` interface and two implementations: `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. We can write our program to use a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayList` specifically. But then our code depends on those specific implementations. So we should write our program to depend on the super type, `List`, instead then our program can work for either of the `List` implementations.

In short this is one rule of OOP design: `Program to an interface`.

Comment: If i cant access method of derived class by obj1 then how it will be preferable.Instead of this i will use obj2 & access both class method(base & derived).May be it is silly question but i am not clear

Comment: Idea is to use the interface as reference variable. IN that case you are free to provide different implementations for the same interface and that wont create any compilation issues. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 0):

The different between the following two lines -

```
Base obj1 = new Derived();
Derived obj2 = new Derived();
```

Is that -

1. for line 1 - you are creating a object of type - `Derived` and storing it in type `Base` variable , this is legal , since `Derived` class is a sub-class of `Base` , but when you do that, using `obj1` , you cannot call functions defined in `Derived` class, example -

   obj1.print()

This would throw an error , because the type of object `obj1` is `Base` (class) and there is no print function in that. To be able to call `print` function for `obj1`  you would need to cast `obj1` to `Derived` class and call the function , like -

```
((Derived)obj1).print()
```

In this case, you are casting the obj1 to type Derived, and hence compiler now knows that `obj1` can call the `print()` function.

2. In line 2 , you are directly creating an object of type `Derived` and storing it in `Derived` type variable.

This is just one example of how they are different, there can be other examples as well .