# Difference between creating an object of subclass in SuperClass Vs Subclass

Tags: java, oop, object

What is the difference between creating an object of the subclass, in subclass and superclass?

My superclass is  -> LibraryItem.Java

My Subclass is  -> Book.java

what is the difference between 1 and 2

```
         1. LibraryItem book_01 = new Book() //In superclass
         2. book_01 = new Book() //In subclass
```

Note:- please note I removed some get, set and some abstract methods. only the important parts have been added here

```
 public abstract class LibraryItem {  
    private boolean status;
    private String borrowedDateTime;
    private Reader reader;
    private int isbn;
    private String title;
    private String publicationDate;
    private String sector;

    public abstract void getItemDetails();
    public abstract void returnItem();
    public abstract void readerDetails();
    public abstract void borrowItem();

    public static void main (String [] args){

    }

}


public class Book extends LibraryItem {
public String author;
    public String publisher;
    public int no_Of_Pages;
    private int readerID;

    Book[] bookArray = new Book[100];

    Book(int isbn, String title, String sector, String publicationDate,
         boolean status, String borrowedDateTime, String author, String publisher, int no_Of_Pages, int readerId){
        super();
        this.setIsbn(isbn);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setSector(sector);
        this.setPublicationDate(publicationDate);
        this.setStatus(status);
        this.setBorrowedDateTime(borrowedDateTime);
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.no_Of_Pages = no_Of_Pages;
        this.setReaderID(readerId);

    }





    //Create 100 Books

    public void createBooks(){
        Book book_01;
        book_01 = new Book(00001, "Harry Potter", "Adveture", "2012.12.12",
                true, "asd","J.K Rowling", "Disney", 500, 0);
        bookArray [0] = book_01;

    }

}
```

Comment: There should be no difference no matter where you create an instance of a class. What are you exactly trying to find?

Comment: `new Book();` does the same thing assuming `Book` is the same class. What is your doubt?

Comment: I have an array " bookList [] " in the subclass, I wanted to add the object to the array. I wanted to know, as per true OOP rules where should I create the object.

Also, the object has the attributes from the superclass, which is an abstract class and attributes from the subclass.

Comment: Can you post the code of your super and sub class and show your code where you are trying to add objects in bookList[] array?

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question with its *real* intention. For now it looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: If you could post a [mcve] it would be much easier to help you. The details of exactly where you're doing what *may* matter a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Superclass reference to subclass object showing same behaviour as subclass reference to subclass object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807029/superclass-reference-to-subclass-object-showing-same-behaviour-as-subclass-refer)

Comment: @MohamedSajjadh i have given explanation for ,whether to use subclass reference or superclass reference .But in your code there is no  LibraryItem book_01 = new Book()  but you have mentioned it at the top

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala Yes, true... but you can see it in the Book class, so I changed it after the comment. Since there are no different as you mentioned it seemed to be appropriate in Book class since I will not be able to access child class methods if I create the object in Super. Moreover, it's an abstract superclass, so I must have access to subclass methods. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MohamedSajjadh yep that's the spirit and don't mention thanks in comment section .If my answer is helpful to you ,give me a upvote and that keeps us moving to aid other developers like you

Comment: Side issue: you appear to be ignoring answers to two of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems bit bizzare but

### IN JAVA:

The non-static methods depends on the runtime (runtime binding type)type of the 
object rather than the reference that points to.

IN your case,
both the time book_01 points to Book class object in heap

Pros  of using superclass reference :
1.Pros is One can give any address of subclass object to superclass ,useful in case of runtime binding if we don't know the exact object type

2.Cons is using the superclass object referring to subclass object we cannot call methods and attributes of subclass.

Pros and cons of using subclass reference:

1.Pros is the object can have access to superclass attributes and methods and also to its too.

2.Cons is the object cannot act as reference to other class unless or until they are subclasses of this class.